# Windows Phone ContentProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Im using UserControl in my Windows Phone 8 project and i want to put some contols like this

```
<MyUserControl>
    <Grid Name="MyGrid">
        ...
    </Grid>
</MyUserControl>
```

I write this code:

```
[ContentProperty("MyContent")]
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyContent",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object MyContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(MyContentProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyContentProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML-file of MyUserControl :

```
<UserControl x:Name="RootUserControl"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    ...>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ContentPresenter Name="Presenter" Content="{Binding MyContent, ElementName=RootUserControl}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It's work, but partly. When I try to use MyGrid or something else into MyUserControl it returns null. What's wrong?

Comment: RootUserControl is not a MyUserControl. Additionally this wont work because a UI element can only be a child of one other UI element...

Comment: I specify DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"